# how to remove the old of python 3.x and keep the latest pyhon 3.x

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python

I'm using ubuntu 18.04, my default python3 version is Python 3.6.6
Found 3 version of python (3.5.2, 3.6.6, 3.7.0) in my pc. I'm not sure how this happened.

/usr/bin/python3.5: Python 3.5.2
/usr/bin/python3.6: Python 3.6.6
/usr/bin/python3.7: Python 3.7.0

Is it safe to remove python 3.5 and python 3.6 using `sudo apt-get purge python3.x` and keep python 3.7 as my default?
because many said if i remove python 3.6 i won't be able to login after restart?

Comment: No it's not use a virtual environment instead!

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Please Google that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NEVER remove (or change) the version of Python included during system install.

Critical system services depend upon that specific version. Removing or changing the version of python will break your system quite horribly.